# Cordova 'deviceready' event not firing from within angular .run block

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova

I'm having issues getting 'deviceready' to register from inside of AngularJS. I'm certain this was working before, so I'm not sure what's changed.

If I call 'deviceready' from a global addEventListener, it works, like so:

```
document.addEventListener('deviceready', function(){
   localStorage.deviceReadyGlobal = true;
});
```

deviceReadyGlobal=true is set. However, if I try to attach this from within Angular, it never fires, like so:

```
app.run(function(){
    document.addEventListener('deviceready', function(){
        localStorage.deviceReadyAngular = true;
    });
});
```

deviceReadyAngular is never set. Now, I understand that PhoneGap probably already fired 'deviceready' while Angular was bootstrapping, but according to the PhoneGap docs, that shouldn't matter.

> The deviceready event behaves somewhat differently from others. Any
>   event handler registered after the deviceready event fires has its
>   callback function called immediately.

Did something change in the behavior of 'deviceready'?

I'm using Cordova 3.3.0 and Angular 1.2.5 currently.

Comment: Not sure why it's not working, but I've always just bootstrapped angular in deviceReady handler.

Comment: Thanks. I know that many PhoneGap/Angular people recommend that approach. I'm trying to avoid it, since we don't have any blocking PhoneGap dependencies in our app bootstrap. We also don't /always/ run the app in PhoneGap.

Comment: I'll bet you're missing the `deviceready` event by attaching your handler too late. Have you tried using a global to catch it before angular starts, and then adding the event in your `run` block only if you haven't already seen the event?

Comment: @JeffHubbard cordova.js hijacks document.addEventListener and modifies it so that it executes the callback function immediately if you try to attach 'deviceready' after it's already fired once. So, it should handle this case properly. I think I have a partial answer though - I'll be writing it up a bit later. Thanks!

Comment: @JasonFarnsworth I think we have a similar problem, did you find a solution?

Comment: @sandstrom Not entirely. I seemed to have two issues. If I used on(), then PhoneGap and Angular seemed to have a conflict with their event handler hijacking. If I used addEventListener(), it just seemed like Angular was executing before cordova.js was loaded. Either way it was fickle, and I ended up moving that code out of Angular. I'm just running it in it's own global namespace now.

Answer (score 5):

This is how I do it inside my app;

```
// Create an application module with dependencies
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

function loadTheApp() {

    // Hide splash screen if any
    if (navigator && navigator.splashscreen) {
        navigator.splashscreen.hide();
    }

    // Initiate FastClick
    FastClick.attach(document.body);

    // Boot AngularJS
    try {
        angular.bootstrap(document, ['myApp']);
    } catch (e) {
        console.log('errrrrrrrrrrrrrr! ' + e);
    }
}

// Listen to device ready
angular.element(document).ready(function() {
    if (window.cordova) {
        document.addEventListener('deviceready', loadTheApp, false);
    } else {
        loadTheApp();
    }
});
```

This way if we are inside a device environement then we listen to deviceready event, if not, then we just ignore that event and load our app.

Answer (score 0):

Either way you could also handle it with `DOMContentLoaded` event handler in javascript way

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
    //alert("Calling DOMContentLoaded");
    document.addEventListener('deviceready', function(){
        //alert("Calling onDeviceReady()");
        initializeYourApp();
    }, false);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I've had this issue. For me the problem was having the  for cordova.js inside the header.

If you generate a sample project from cordova cli, they have the script tag inside the body.

Once i put it in the body ,like the sample project had it, next to the app-root, i started getting the deviceready event